# ASP/ADODB Run-Time Error: 3704

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

Here is Error When I try to open DB.

I don't do any command.

And err.number is not zero.

I have no idea.

```
    Dim strDSN, strMsg
    strDSN = "DSN=Test"

    If Not IsObject(CNNDB) Then
        Set CNNDB= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    End If
    If CNNDB.State = 0 Then
        CNNDB.Open strDSN
        CNNDB.CursorLocation = 3
    End If

    If err.number <> 0 Then
        CNNDB.Close
        Set CNNDB= Nothing

        strMsg = "ErrDesc=" & err.Description & "&ErrCode=" & err.number
        Response.Write strMsg
        Response.End
    End If
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out `CNNDB.Close` ?

Comment: Still Error...I can not understand why I just opened DB on the error

Comment: Still Error, but a different error? Check if you have a working DSN called Test

Comment: The same error. DSN is working.

Comment: If you have a `On Error Resume Next` in your page, comment it out for now and retry.

Comment: Can you add the error message of `Response.Write strMsg` . Try declaring CNNDB before by `Dim CNNDB` before setting the value if you have `Option explicit` defined in you script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the Error Description before DB close.

It will show the truth error message.

```
If err.number <> 0 Then
    strMsg = "ErrDesc=" & err.Description & "&ErrCode=" & err.number
    CNNDB.Close
    Set CNNDB= Nothing

    strMsg = "ErrDesc=" & err.Description & "&ErrCode=" & err.number
    Response.Write strMsg
    Response.End
End If
```